# Who are the sons of God (υἱοῖς θεοῦ) mentioned in Psalms 88:7 LXX

Tags: psalms, son-of-god, god

> ὅτι τίς ἐν νεφέλαις ἰσωθήσεται τῷ κυρίῳ καὶ τίς ὁμοιωθήσεται τῷ κυρίῳ ἐν **υἱοῖς θεοῦ**  Psalm 89:7 LXX

> HEBREW Psalm 89:7 כִּ֤י מִ֣י בַ֭שַּׁחַק יַעֲרֹ֣ךְ לַיהוָ֑ה יִדְמֶ֥ה לַ֜יהוָ֗ה **בִּבְנֵ֥י אֵלִים**׃

> Because who, in clouds, will match the Lord? And who will be equal to the Lord, in children of God? LXX Pbro. Guillermo jünemann beckchaefer

Comment: Lev 17:11; 1 Cor 6:1-3; Heb 12:22-24

Answer (score 3):

Note the triple parallelism of Ps 89:5-7 -

5. The heavens praise Your wonders, O LORD— Your faithfulness as well— in the assembly of the holy ones.
6. For who in the skies can compare with the LORD? Who among the **sons of God** is like the LORD?
7. In the council of the holy ones, God is greatly feared, and awesome above all who surround Him.

Note that all these references are to heavenly beings such as:

- in the heavens/skies [shamayim]
- assembly of holy ones
- those who surround Him [YHWH]

Thus, "sons of God" in this instance has the same meaning as in the book of Job:

- Job 1:6 - One day the **sons of God** came to present themselves before the LORD, and Satan also came with them.
- Job 2:1 - On another day the **sons of God** came to present themselves before the LORD, and Satan also came with them to present himself before Him.
- Job 38:4-7 - **4** Where were you when I laid the foundations of the earth? Tell Me, if you have understanding. **5** Who fixed its measurements? Surely you know! Or who stretched a measuring line across it? **6** On what were its foundations set, or who laid its cornerstone, **7** while the morning stars sang together and all the **sons of God** shouted for joy?